# return statements when doing Extract Method

Tags: c++, refactoring

Let's say you have a very long method, like this:

```
int monster()
{
    int rc = 0;

    // some statements ...

    if (dragonSlayer.on_vacation()) {
        cout << "We are screwed!\n";
        if (callTheKing() == true)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    } else {
        cout << "We are saved!\n";
        slayTheDragon();
    }

    // rest of long method...

    return rc;
}
```

and I'm working on skeletonizing the code. I want to extract the dragon slaying part to

```
int handleDragon() {
    if (dragonSlayer.on_vacation()) {
        cout << "We are screwed!\n";
        if (callTheKing() == true)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    } else {
        cout << "We are saved!\n";
        slayTheDragon();
    }

    return 0; // ?
}
```

and replace the code in monster() with a call to handleDragon().

But there is a problem. There is a return statement in the middle of that part. If I keep the part where the return code of handleDragon() is handled, it will keep the litter in the big method.

Besides using exceptions, is there an elegant and safe way to refactor this piece of code out of the monster method? How should these types of situations be handled?

Comment: If you're going to compare booleans with `true` like that, then note that `callTheKing() == true` is also a boolean. So it should be `(callTheKing() == true) == true`.

Comment: More seriously, if you're going to use return values rather than exceptions, then you need a consistent scheme. Here you have one function returning `int` (with zero for success) and others (apparently) returning `bool` (with zero for failure). You're just asking for someone to mix up the two schemes.

Answer (score 2):

Return 0 from the `handleDragon` method if the dragon slayer is available:

```
int handleDragon() {
    if (dragonSlayer.on_vacation()) {
        cout << "We are screwed!\n";
        if (callTheKing() == true)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    } else {
        cout << "We are saved!\n";
        slayTheDragon();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then back in the `monster` method, if the return value was greater than zero, return that value, otherwise carry on:

```
// some statements ...

int handleDragonResult = handleDragon();
if (handleDragonResult > 0) {
    return handleDragonResult;
}

// rest of long method...
```

You should also document the `handleDragon` method, to explain the value that gets returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
enum DragonHandled { DHSuccess, DHKing, DHNoKing };

inline DragonHandled askForKing()
{
    if (callTheKing())
        return DHKing;
    else
        return DHNoKing;
}

DragonHandled handleDragon()
{
    if (dragonSlayer.on_vacation()) {
        cout << "We are screwed!\n";
        return askForKing();
    }
    cout << "We are saved!\n";
    slayTheDragon();
    return DHSuccess;
}

int monster()
{
    some_statements(...);

    DragonHandled handled = handleDragon();
    if( handled != DHSuccess )
      return handled; // enum to int is an implicit cast

    return more_statements(...);
}
```

- Except for a function that returns an actual *signed number*, I would not return `int`. If the result has a meaning, define that meaning properly (that is: an `enum`).
- A function *does* something, and whatever it does, should be visible in its name. So there should be a ***verb*** in a function's name (*`handle`*`dragon()`, *`call`*`TheKing()`). `monsters` isn't a verb, it isn't something you can do. If I see an identifier `monsters`, I'd think it's a container for monsters.
- Checking `if(x == true)` is just useless noise, since `if(x)` is terser, simpler and just as true.

Comment: "monster" was simply my way of pointing out that this is a monster method, it's not a real method for my code. I just created imaginary code to state a problem I encountered.

Comment: It's quite common to verb words like "monster" round my way.

Comment: @Mike: I'm a non-native, so I could be wrong here. I wouldn't have thought you could turn this into a verb. Mea culpa...

Comment: you're right, it's not standard English, but sometimes used as slang in some parts of the UK.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do this:

```
int handleDragon() {
    int rc = 0;

    if (dragonSlayer.on_vacation()) {
        cout << "We are screwed!\n";
        if (callTheKing() == true)
            rc = 1;
        else
            rc = 2;
    } else {
        cout << "We are saved!\n";
        slayTheDragon();
    }

    return rc;
}
```

and then:

```
int monster()
{
    int rc = 0;

    // some statements ...

    rc = handleDragon();

    // rest of long method... 

    return rc;
}
```

or if you want to do something with the return code:

```
int monster()
{
    int rc = 0;

    // some statements ...

    int handleDragonReturnCode = handleDragon();

    if(handleDragonReturnCode == 0) {
       // do something
    }

    else {
      // do something else
    }

    // rest of long method... 

    return rc;
}
```

Is this what you want? On a general note, avoid using *magic numbers* like `1` and `2` for your return codes. Use constants, `#define`, or `enum`.

Concerning `return`, try to have *one* exit point from your function. As you have found out, having multiple `return` statements can make refactoring hard (as well as understanding the logic unless it's really simply).

Comment: _Single entry, single exit_ is a dumb left-over from the dark era of pure structured programming and long-winded functions, pouring over several pages on the monitor. Sticking to it lulls you into believing you are safe to assume that a function won't prematurely return - which is never true, since in C++ we have exceptions. Make your functions short and _express the control flow through control flow statements_ rather than by manipulating a return variable, hiding the actual algorithm under `if` statements that all test for the return variable's state.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a "dumb left-over". I'd say it's the exception rather than the rule. The reason I say it is because it's easy to abuse multiple returns and I've seen that far too many times. Hence, the cautionary note. I agree with what you say in general though regarding flow-control.

Answer (score 0):

The question was about the strategy so I think the answer by Richard Fearn is a good one.

To make it into a refactoring pattern it would look something like:

**Context**: A section in the middle of a larger method is to be extracted.

**Problem**: The section contains return statements.

**Solution**:

1. Extract the code to a new method returning the same type as the larger method.
2. Find a value of that type that does not mean anything. Call that value CONTINUE.
3. Add a statement at the end of the new method that returns CONTINUE.
4. In the larger method test the return value from the new method for CONTINUE. If it is not then return that value.

This would be the principal approach. As the next step you could refactor the return values from the new method to something more meaningful (like in the answer from sbi). And you'd have to find a way to handle the case where the return type isn't a scalar or simple type, returning a NULL object or some such.